# "Hiding" javascript events in DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a custom ordering process and I'm using AJAX requests and dynamic forms a lot to complete parts of the ordering process, but I'd like to cleanup the way I'm doing it into terms of the HTML. I'm using jQuery too.

In looking at applications like Google's word processor, I can see that both the DOM and source exhibit no javascript event attributes. For example:

```
<div id="docs-file-menu" role="menuitem" class="menu-button goog-control goog-inline-block" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">File</div>
```

My guess is that a script is registering Javascript events after the fact based on the HTML attributes.

My website is much less complex, but I was wondering how to approach this as I currently have button styled `<a><img></a>` tags (or similar) that call Javascript functions, which works fine, but seems like the lesser (and old school) approach. For example:

```
<a href="javascript:Customisation.beginNewPair()">
    <img src="images/begin-new.gif" />
</a>
```

Comment: You say you're using jQuery? Look at click handlers - they are one of its most useful features. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @AntP I know all about that stuff. I guess I basically answered my own question anyway. "Run a script after the DOM has loaded to inject all your events." Haha.

Comment: If you know all about that stuff, all you need to do is write a click handler for your anchor. I presume. Hard to say, since you haven't actually stated what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AntP I guess my question was, is there some other way (perhaps more automated?) than just adding a script to find each button and add it's particular click handler. But I guess not, unless it's through a web UI framework or something.

Comment: It would be far better to remove the A element, put the listener on the image and use CSS to get an appropriate cursor to display (e.g. 'cursor: pointer').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example on how to use data attributes and an eventListener on click:

```
var a = document.getElementById('docs-file-menu');
a.addEventListener('click', test);

function test () {
var dis = a.getAttribute('aria-disabled');
var exp = a.getAttribute('aria-expanded');
var has = a.getAttribute('aria-haspopup');


    if (dis == 'true') {
        alert('disabled = true');
    }
     if (exp == 'true') {
        alert('expanded = true');
    }
    if (has == 'true') {
        alert('haspopup = true');
    }

}
```

You also could access the different data attributes on page load and, according to them, you could be running different functions.

Here's a simple [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbhkjgo7/) with onclick event, simply click on File

Comment: I had a feeling it was as simple as a post-DOM script manually adding the events...

Comment: It is very easy, but very useful

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `addEventListener`.

How you access the elements is another question, but say you want an alert every time somebody clicks on a box.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.addEventListener('click', function(){ alert(); });
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width:150px;height:150px;background:blue;"></div>
```

You can also put what happens in a real function:

```js
function doSomething(){ 
    alert();
}

var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width:150px;height:150px;background:blue;"></div>
```